# Grouping by day for distinct user logins

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by, where-clause

Trying to get the count of logins for each day for each distinct user.
My query however does not group by date:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS Date
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd,-30,GETDATE())


SELECT CAST(ml.login_time AS date) AS Date_Login
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT ml.email) AS Total
FROM database.login AS ml
WHERE 1=1
    AND ml.login_time > @StartDate
GROUP BY ml.login_time
ORDER BY ml.login_time DESC
```

The ouput gives me something like this:

```
2018-12-11  1
2018-12-11  5
2018-12-11  2
2018-12-11  2
2018-12-11  1
2018-12-11  3
2018-12-10  1
2018-12-10  2
2018-12-10  3
```

Comment: `GROUP BY CAST(ml.login_time AS date)`?

Comment: please post your asnwer to mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  You are not grouping by the date, you are grouping by the time.

You need to repeat the conversion in the `group by` and `order by` clauses:

```
SELECT CAST(ml.login_time AS date) as Date_Login,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ml.email) as Total
FROM database.login AS ml
WHERE ml.login_time > @StartDate
GROUP BY CAST(ml.login_time AS date)
ORDER BY CAST(ml.login_time AS date) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `GROUP BY ml.login_time` clause does not match your `SELECT CAST(ml.login_time AS date)`. Hence you are grouping by login time, and getting duplicated rows on the `CAST`.

Try :

```
SELECT 
CAST(ml.login_time AS date) AS Date_Login,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ml.email) AS Total
FROM database.login AS ml
WHERE ml.login_time > @StartDate
GROUP BY CAST(ml.login_time AS date)
ORDER BY CAST(ml.login_time AS date) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You're displaying the date of login, but you're grouping by datetime.

Make sure you use the same CAST() in your GROUP BY as in your SELECT:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS Date
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd,-30,GETDATE())

SELECT CAST(ml.login_time AS date) AS Date_Login
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT ml.email) AS Total
FROM database.login AS ml
WHERE 1=1
    AND ml.login_time > @StartDate
GROUP BY CAST(ml.login_time AS date)
ORDER BY ml.login_time DESC
```